# How to prevent models being generated with full namespace?

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

When I run `openapi-generator-cli` the Models and containing files are being output with their names containing the full namespace of the API classes. This is very awkward to read. I'd like the output to contain only the Model name, without the namespace.

E.g for class

```
namespace My.NameSpace.Common.V1.Models.Dto
{
    public partial class PortfolioAsset
    {
        // properties
```

The output looks like

```
my-namespace-common-v1-models-dto-portfolio-asset.ts
```

With the content of the file as

```
export interface MyNamespaceCommonV1ModelsDtoPortfolioAsset { 
    // parameters
}
```

I just want the file to be called `portfolio-asset.ts` and the content to be

```
export interface PortfolioAsset { 
    // parameters
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was simply to remove the `CustomSchemaIds` line, which specified that I should use the full name of each type being generated.

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = AppSettingsProvider.AppSettings.ApplicationName, Version = "v1" });
            // c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName); <-- delete ftw
        });
```

Comment: However - I believe when you have two files with the same name you will get a collision. Don't have any proof tho :)